# Could genAI be used to generate reasonable scientific hypotheses?

Tags: prompt-design

Suppose I have a trained genAI and I give it some different experiments, their results, and I were to ask it to generate a plausible hypotheses of what happend. Would it be able to do this well? If not, why?

I am pretty sure the answer is not, otherwise there'd be a wider application of AI in the applied sciences as of right now.

Comment: Welcome to [genai.se]. The question is unclear / needs more details. I.E. there are several GPT foundation models. Which one are you using? There are many ways to perform GPT training, how do you perform it?

Comment: It seems like this question is asking for a proof of concept.  It's asking if it's possible with *any* genAI.  So "which one are you using?" is not relevant.

Answer (score 6):

- ["Can ChatGPT be used to generate scientific hypotheses?"](https://arxiv.org/abs/2304.12208) directly asks GPT-4 for hypotheses and reports a number of successes ("nontrivial predictions that some of us are motivated enough to test out in the lab"). The authors attempted to ensure that these didn't already exist in human-written content, though this isn't possible with absolute certainty. They do also note that it is prone to obvious errors, and consider human curation of the hypotheses to currently still be essential.
- ["Harnessing the Power of Adversarial Prompting and Large Language Models for Robust Hypothesis Generation in Astronomy"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2306.11648.pdf) uses GPT-4 with document retrieval on astronomy papers to reduce hallucination. As a quality rating, evaluation with human judges gave "a near-expert level of 4/5 when 1,000 papers were included" - where "3/5 corresponds to a typical hypothesis by a competent PhD student".

Both papers found value in having GPT-4 critique its own ideas to improve the hypotheses.